# Position of an element in a multidimensional array [ C ]

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, position

I have to write a function that receives an integer X (the value of the linearized position)  and an array that contains the dimensions of a multidimensional array and it has to save in a second array the coordinates of the element with position X in the multidimensional reference system. For example:

X=2 and array[]={A,B} where the array contains the dimensions(A,B) of a 2D matrix in this example. So the position in 2D reference system is:

Knowing:  **X=x*B+y** ----> **x=X/B**  and  **y=X%B** ----> **position[]={x,y};**

So it was simple to decipher X into x and y because it was the banal case of a 2D matrix but my program has to deal with N-dimensional matrix (So it has to decipher X into position x,y,......,n) .

My idea is to apply the algorithm that I've showed but even I can't find a C code that can deal with a generic N-dimensional matrix (I also tried to write a recursive function without success).

Can someone find a solution to this problem? (Thank you in advance!!!)

I'm a beginner!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you have an array DIM2[X,Y] with dimenstions Xn and Yn, you could represent this (as you said) as a one dimenstional array too.

A[x,y] would then be mapped to DIM1[x + y * Xn]

DIM1 must have size (Xn * Yn)

3 dimension array B[] with dimensions Xn,Yn,Zn could be mapped the same way:

B[x,y,z] would map to DIM1 [ x + y * Xn + z * Xn * Yn], DIM1 must be able to hold (Xn * Yn * Zn) items, 
B[x,y,z,a] would map to DIM1 [ x + y * Xn + z * Xn * Yn + a *  Xn *  Yn *
 Zn]

and so on

for a generic N dimensional array, a recursion would be best, where an array with 100 dimensions is array of 99-dimensional arrays. If all dimenstions have the same size, that would be relative simple (writing it, i also mentioned that the recursion can be easily unrolled into a simple for-loop, find it below)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <malloc.h>

    #define max_depth  5    /* 5 dimensions        */
    #define size      10    /* array[10] of array  */

    // recursive part, do not use this one
    int _getValue( int *base, int offset, int current, int *coords) {
        if (--current)
           return _getValue (base + *coords*offset, offset/size, current, coords+1);

        return base[*coords];
    }
    // recursive part, do not use this one
    void _setValue( int *base, int offset, int current, int *coords, int newVal) {
        if (--current)
           _setValue (base + *coords*offset, offset/size, current, coords+1, newVal);
        base[*coords]=newVal;
    }

    // getValue: read item
    int getValue( int *base, int *coords) {
        int offset=pow( size, max_depth-1);   /* amount of ints to skip for first dimension */
        return (_getValue (base, offset, max_depth, coords));
    }
    // setValue: set an item
    void setValue( int *base, int *coords, int newVal) {
        int offset=pow( size, max_depth-1);
        _setValue (base, offset, max_depth, coords, newVal);
    }

    int main() {
        int items_needed = pow( size, max_depth);

        printf ("allocating room for %i items\n", items_needed);
        int *dataholder = (int *) malloc(items_needed*sizeof(int));
        if (!dataholder) {
            fprintf (stderr,"out of memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
        int coords1[5] = { 3,1,2,1,1 };    // access member [3,1,2,1,1]
        setValue(dataholder, coords1, 4711);
        int coords2[5] = { 3,1,0,4,2 };
        int x = getValue(dataholder, coords2);

        int coords3[5] = { 9,7,5,3,9 };
        /* or: access without recursion: */
        int i, posX = 0;                           // position of the wanted integer
        int skip = pow( size, max_depth-1);        // amount of integers to be skipped for "pick"ing array
        for (i=0;i<max_depth; i++) {
            posX += coords3[i] * skip;             // use array according to current coordinate
            skip /= size;                          // calculate next dimension's size
        }
        x = dataholder[posX];

        return x;
    }
```

Comment: I thought about recursion several times but every time I was unable to write down a code...I would be so happy if someone can show the solving code :)

Comment: the "idea" about it is simple: on each "step", you just pick the correct underlying array. assume x is 3, then you pick the 3rd array, and go head picking y: you pick array[y] up til the place where you have only one array left. there you finally pick the item

Comment: I updated the answer. i think for a C-Beginner, the 3rd access variant (using the for-loop to find out the index) is easier to understand since there's a lot less pointer arithmetic involved

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the code does in the for cycle. I'm supposed to have an array that show me a list of coordinates starting from posX. If posX=0 the obviously the coordinates are [0 0 0 0 0 ... 0] depending on the dimension of my native multidimensional matrix. We consider posX the integer value of the position of an element of an array which is the linearization of my N-dimensional matrix. We are not interested on the value of the element itself but is our interest is to decipher posX into coordinates of my N-dimensional matrix.

Comment: So X=x*B+y ----> If X=2 and array[]={A,B} with A=2 and B=2 ----> x=2/2 and y=2%2 ----> position[]={x,y};------->OUTPUT: position[0]=1 and position[1]=0 as expected.

Comment: X=x*B+y is used to "concat" each row into a single stream (0,0) will be 0, (0,1) 1 (1,0) 2 and (1,1) 3 ... each further dimension does the same with the concated ones